# In VS Code, how can I break my project into multiple files?

Tags: python, project

I am trying to make a transition from Matlab to Python.  I completed the Udemy Python Bootcamp; it used Jupyter Notebook, which was a fine learning environment.  Now I'm trying to use VS Code - It has nice debugging features, but I can't figure out how to break a program into separate files.

In Matlab, my top-level program for a project would call functions that were in separate files in the same folder.  I just tried to do the same with a simple Python program in VS Code, and got a weird error message.  If I put the function and main program in the same file, then it works.

How can I use separate files for my Python functions, and have the top-level program know how to find them?

Comment: if you have anything useful in your notebooks you must have used `import` to use some library, read the python docs for `import`, or any of the many websites

Comment: Your question doesn't really have anything to do with VS Code — although the IDE does have a something that goes by the name "project" — it's about how Python locates modules (i.e other .py files) when you import them. There are hundreds of question on that topic here, and it's also described in the documentation as well as most tutorials. Stackoverflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: To get some understanding see [The import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Hi martineau.  I really did look VS Code Tutorials and Help, and then Google and stackoverflow, but wasn't finding the answer.  I did learn "import" in my Python course, but it applied to modules that had been downloaded and installed with "pip".  It was not at all obvious to me that the same command was needed for my own functions.  As I said, I'm transitioning from Matlab, which automatically would find such functions if stored in the same folder.  Please be patient with an old dog learning new tricks.  Thank you, Eliot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `import` the file at the beginning of your python script.
Example: If you have `main.py` and `function.py` and want to use the function `test()` from `function.py`, you have to write
the code below in your `main.py` file.

```
import function

function.test()
```

***or***

```
from function import test

test()
```

Comment: Mario - Thank you!  I had copied part of my Tic Tac Toe game from the Python course.  Per your advice, I added "from display_board import display_board" to the calling program:
test_board = ['#','X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O','X']
display_board(test_board)

Comment: Technically `import`s *will* work even if they're not at the beginning of a script (i.e. it's not a requirement (despite what PEP 8 seems to [imply](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports))), although that is the recommended and usually the best location . They *do* however need to have been *executed* before references to them or things `import`ed `from` them are referenced.